# Bison %union use

Tags: bison

So, I've set up an AST within my .y grammar, example snippet below of how it's used:

```
typedef struct node
{
  struct node *left;
  struct node *right;
  char *token;
} node;

...

exp    : term             {$$ = $1;}
        | exp PLUS term     {$$ = mknode($1, $3, "+");}
        | exp MINUS term    {$$ = mknode($1, $3, "-");}
        ;
...
node *mknode(node *left, node *right, char *token)
{
  /* malloc the node */
  node *newnode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
  char *newstr = (char *)malloc(strlen(token)+1);
  strcpy(newstr, token);
  newnode->left = left;
  newnode->right = right;
  newnode->token = newstr;
  return(newnode);
 }
```

My question is, set up like this, is it still possible to use %union for other values?
i.e.

```
%union{
    int value;
}
exp    : term             {
                             $$ = $1;
                             $<value>$ = $<value>1;
                          }
        | exp PLUS term     {
                               if($<value>1 == $<value>3) {
                                   $$ = mknode($1, $3, "+");
                                   $<value>$ = $<value>1;
                               }
                            }
...etc
```

Or does setting $$ overwrite the ability to use union variables?

Comment: `$$` *is* the union variable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example shows assigning two values to different elements of the same union, so the second value will overwrite the first value.  `$$` is the union-valued stack slot that the current action is generating, while `$1` and `$3` are the union-valued slots corresponding to those non-terminals, which were written into `$$` in those rules' actions.

Using `<type>` just overrides the default field in the union to use, which is normally determined by the `%type` declarations in your code (which you don't show).  So if you had
 `%type <value> exp` in your code, the `$$` and `$<value>$` refer to the same thing -- the `value` field of the `yyval` variable that will be pushed on the bison value stack after the action runs.

If you want to have multiple values for the same non-terminal on bison value stack, use a struct in the union:

```
%union {
    struct {
        node *node;
        int value;
    } node_and_value;
    :
}

%type <node_and_value> exp term

%%

exp    : term             {
                             $$ = $1; /* copy the whole struct */
                             /* this is the default action, so could be left off */
                          }
        | exp PLUS term   {
                              if($1.value == $3.value) {
                                  $$.node = mknode($1.node, $3.node, "+");
                                  $$.value = $1.value;
                              } else {
                                  ...
                              }
                          }
```